# OMAPI in Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-emulator, smartcard, secure-element, open-mobile-api

Recently, I have read about Smart Card API (Open Mobile API) and figured out that not every device can work with a secure element as the Smart Card API is not implemented on every device. So can anybody say if I can work with a secure element of Android Emulator SIM card if I have no physical SIM card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not on the stock Android emulator. The Android emulator (AVD) that ships with the ANdroid SDK does not currently support the Open Mobile API either.

However, the [SEEK-for-Android project](https://seek-for-android.github.io/) provides patches to the Android emulator to allow a secure element to be attached over PC/SC (smart card) or MSD (uSD card). [Detailed instructions can be found in their wiki.](https://github.com/seek-for-android/pool/wiki/EmulatorExtension). Be aware though, that those patches seem to target some Android 4.2.2 and might not work out-of-the-box with other Android versions.

Comment: Is there any possibility to use a virtual smart card for an Android device, so I could change my smart cards when it needed and send APDU commands to this cards from my app? Such an approach could help me not to change my SIM cards or other smart cards multiple times.

Comment: probably it's not a correct question. if so - sorry. i'm new to this topic.

Comment: @NazariyMoshenskiy I'm not sure I can follow what you are trying to ask. Could you elaborate what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have an application which works with Secure Element of SIM card. If I have 5 SIM cards and want to test another card I need to change a card in my card reader. So, can I create a virtual card from my SIM card and connect to it from my application as it was in my card reader?